# automatically enter text in to a password prompt

Tags: powershell, vbscript, symantec

Is there a way to automatically enter text in to a password prompt window in ms windows with script .

I am attempting remove a product that will not allow removal when the password is applied , how ever passing the password in CMD does not work as the prompt will all ways appear .

Product SEP 12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will help you or not, but:

http://wasp.codeplex.com/

Comment: POWERSHELL-WASP found this on a SEP Site `Clear-Content c:\log.log Start-Process "msiexec" -Args "/x {F4A73EC6-EFC4-488D-AF1A-F2C3CD1BC072} /qb-! /l*v c:\log.log" Start-Sleep -Seconds 10 do { $log = Get-Content c:\log.log Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 } until ($log[-2] -match "CheckUninstallPassword") Import-Module '.\WASP.dll' Select-Window * | Select-ChildWindow | Send-Keys "%CHANGE_TO_REQUIRED_PASSWORD%" Select-Window * | Select-ChildWindow | Send-Keys "{ENTER}"`

Comment: I'd say that might qualify as 'helpful'.  :)